# 404 Not Found when connect to Google app engine endpoint

Tags: android, google-app-engine

I'm trying to connect to google endpoint in android app but when I run the app on emulator or real device both are not work and I get error 404 not found.
so I create button that implement the asynctask of connection :

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    }

    public void tellJoke(View view) {

        EndpointsAsyncTask asyncTask = new EndpointsAsyncTask(this);
        asyncTask.execute();
}
}
```

and this is the class of asynctask:

```
public class EndpointsAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {
    private static MyApi myApiService = null;
    private Context mContext;

    public EndpointsAsyncTask (Context context){
        mContext = context;
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
        if(myApiService == null) {  // Only do this once
            MyApi.Builder builder = new
                    MyApi.Builder(AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport(),
                    new AndroidJsonFactory(), null)
                    // options for running against local devappserver
                    // ­ 10.0.2.2 is localhost's IP address in Android emulator
                    // ­ turn off compression when running against local devappserver
                    .setRootUrl("http://10.0.2.2:8080/_ah/api/")
                    .setGoogleClientRequestInitializer(new GoogleClientRequestInitializer() {
                        @Override                         public void initialize(AbstractGoogleClientRequest<?>
                                                                                         abstractGoogleClientRequest) throws IOException {
                            abstractGoogleClientRequest.setDisableGZipContent(true);
                        }
                    });
            // end options for devappserver

            myApiService = builder.build();
        }


        try {
            return myApiService.jokes().execute().getData();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            return e.getMessage();
        }
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, AndroidLibraryActivity.class);

        intent.putExtra("jokes", result);
        mContext.startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

and in android library I received the result like this:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_android_library);

        TextView jokes;
        jokes = findViewById(R.id.jokes);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String joke = intent.getStringExtra("jokes");

            jokes.setText(joke);

    }
```

and this is my endpoint:

```
@Api(
        name = "myApi",
        version = "v1",
        namespace = @ApiNamespace(
                ownerDomain = "backend.builditbigger.gradle.udacity.com",
                ownerName = "backend.builditbigger.gradle.udacity.com",
                packagePath = ""
        )
)
public class MyEndpoint {

    /** A simple endpoint method that takes a name and says Hi back */

    @ApiMethod(name = "jokes")
    public MyBean jokes(){
        MyBean response = new MyBean();
        Joker jokes = new Joker();
        String jokesResult = jokes.getJoke();
        response.setData(jokesResult);
        return response;
    }
```

also I read many solutions but nothing work with me and by the way when I run it on real device I change the rooturl to this link:

> http://builditbigger-id.appspot.com/_ah/api/

but it doesn't work so how make it work at least on the simulator devices!

Comment: Are you sure you are hitting the URL? A 404 means you hit a server (some server) and it's going to a route that can't be resolved.

Can you paste the URL into the emulator's browser and see if the emulator can reach it?

Also, 10.0.0.2 is one of the addresses of your machine. Are you sure the development server is serving that address? It defaults to 127.0.0.1.